# Limit the size of the modal Popup in Flex ?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, canvas, actionscript-2

```
private function tileList_itemClick2(evt:ListEvent):void {
                img = new Image();
                    img.maintainAspectRatio = true;
                    img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_complete);
                    img.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, image_resize);
                    img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, image_click);           

                    img.source = "products/images/" + evt.itemRenderer.data.imgH;
                    img.setStyle("addedEffect", image_addedEffect);
                    img.setStyle("removedEffect", image_removedEffect);
                    PopUpManager.addPopUp(img, myCanvas, true); 
             }
```

Is it possible to limit the size of the modal Popup ("modal transparency color") such that it is contained inside a Canvas?

Comment: I am not certain what exactly you are asking.  Could you elaborate?  Would a titleWindow be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The PopUpManager in Flex is designed to display modal pop-ups over the entire application. You cannot limit it to a smaller region.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` properties.